# How to bind form input to object?

Tags: forms, angular

I have the following form:

```
<form role="form" [ngFormModel]="userEditForm"  (ngSubmit)="editUser(user)">
<div>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" #username id="username" placeholder="Username" [ngFormControl]="userEditForm.controls['username']">
</div>
<div>
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" #firstName id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" [ngFormControl]="userEditForm.controls['firstName']">
</div>
<div>
    <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" #lastName  id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" [ngFormControl]="userEditForm.controls['lastName']">
</div>
<div>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" #email  id="email" placeholder="Email" [ngFormControl]="userEditForm.controls['email']">
</div>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

And in my component I have defined:

```
        constructor(private _routeParams:RouteParams, private _formBuilder:FormBuilder, private _UserInject:UserInject){
    this.userEditForm = _formBuilder.group({
        'firstName': [this.user.firstName],
        'lastName': [this.user.lastName],
        'username': [this.user.username],
        'email': [this.user.email],
    })
}

ngOnInit(){
    let id = this._routeParams.get('userId');
    this.user = this._UserInject.getUser(id);
}
```

}

However, this creates an error, because this.user is not yet defined in the constructor. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

It works when I use formBuilder in the ngOnInit - however, I am not sure if thats a proper way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Just move

```
this.userEditForm = _formBuilder.group({
    'firstName': [this.user.firstName],
    'lastName': [this.user.lastName],
    'username': [this.user.username],
    'email': [this.user.email],
})
```

after the code where you assign `this.user` (into `ngOnInit()`)

Comment: Does it create two-way data binding between form and component?

Comment: Sure, Angular checks after each event if bound values have changed.